# Add Stripe Connect data to wc_stripe_payment_request

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

I am using Stripe Connect to collect a commission for sales on a woocommerce site.

I need to add the following to the payment request JSON.

```
  'application_fee_amount' => (Gateway Based Fees Amount),
  'transfer_data' => [
    'destination' => '{{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}',
  ],
```

This code I found and modified a little to fit my purpose. EDIT: I have completely rewritten this, I just need to get the extra variable array values added to the request.

```
//add_filter( 'woocommerce_stripe_request_body', 'add_application_fee', 20, 2 );
add_filter('wc_stripe_generate_payment_request', 'add_application_fee', 20, 3 );

function add_application_fee( $post_data ) {
    //$applicationFee = (int)apply_filters('vnm_wc_stripe_connect_application_fee', $order, $request);
    $applicationFee = 25;  //  <- Use this for testing, I 
    $post_data['application_fee_amount'] = $applicationFee;
    $post_data['on_behalf_of'] = 'acct_1GQjzOHenYA2KZ8B';
    $post_data['transfer_data']['destination'] = 'acct_1GQjzOHenYA2KZ8B';
    return $post_data;
}
```

This does not produce any errors, however the information does not get added onto the stripe payment.

```
{
  "amount": "12766",
  "currency": "USD",
  "description": "Order 35215",
  "metadata": {
    "instance": "example.com",
    "order_id": "35215",
    "order_email": "example@gmail.com",
    "cart_hash": ""
  },
  "setup_future_usage": "off_session",
  "capture_method": "automatic",
  "confirmation_method": "manual",
  "customer": "cus_H1VGhq2aNJWokc"
}
```

Comment: Did you solved this issue? I have same usecase to implement, Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

`wc_stripe_generate_payment_request` passes 3 arguments. Take a look at the source code:

```
/**
    * Filter the return value of the WC_Payment_Gateway_CC::generate_payment_request.
    *
    * @since 3.1.0
    * @param array $post_data
    * @param WC_Order $order
    * @param object $source
    */
    return apply_filters( 'wc_stripe_generate_payment_request', $post_data, $order, $prepared_source );
```

Try setting the correct amount of arguments to the filter hook, otherwise it won't get called.

```
add_filter('wc_stripe_generate_payment_request', 'add_application_fee', 10, 3);
```

Comment: I originally had that and took them out to let the defaults set. No difference ether way. Is there a log where I could find out if my function is getting called? I was thinking of writing a log line in the function to a file.

Comment: You'll find the Woocommerce logs section by going to Woocommerce > Status > Logs. You have to manually choose the Stripe generated log in the select element and then click 'View'.

Answer (score 0):

This is known issue (~bug). See

- https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-gateway-stripe/issues/884 and
- https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-gateway-stripe/issues/791

The first link provides a workaround - use add_filter( 'woocommerce_stripe_request_body', 'add_application_fee', 20, 2 )

The second link points out that you have to modify the Javascript call as well (very easy to forget!)

"indextwo commented on 23 Feb 2019
... something I missed in the Stripe docs: if you're creating a Stripe source and intending to send a direct charge to a Connected account, you need to include that as part of the Stripe() call in JavaScript:

var stripe = Stripe(wc_stripe_params.key);

becomes

var stripe = Stripe(wc_stripe_params.key, {stripeAccount: acct_CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID});"